# Python case sensitive removal

Tags: python, bots

I'm making a small bot for twitch . tv and I have a small issue that I don't know how to fix it.

```
user = getUser(line)
message = getMessage(line)
if "Pls Work" in message.lower():
    sendMessage(s, "Okay I will work :)")
    break
```

I don't want to put loads of different combinations for one text, so how do I make it so it converts the input into lower cases so the bot understands it? I tried to put lower() in many places but didn't seem to work.

Comment: but `if "Pls Work" in message.lower()` is not possible because the left hand expression has uppercase letters... `if "pls work"` would work

Comment: Thanks ! was simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if `Pls Work` is in a message of only lower case letters. It contains upper case letters, hence the `if` condition will never be satisfied.

Just do as follows:

```
if "pls work" in message.lower():
    #stuff
```

here's a simple test in the Python console of what I'm saying:

```
>>> message = "Hello Pls Work Bot"
>>> print "pls work" in message.lower()
True
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That was simple fix :)

Comment: yeah it was! Well, you can mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem. This will mark the question as solved and might help other users. (and get me reputation lol)

Comment: I did now, I had to wait to mark it as answered it had a timer on it or something lol

Comment: oh I did not know that there was a minimum time to wait, sorry lol Thanks!